# Asp.net core application is not accessible from an external load balanced Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a VM behind an external load balancer in Azure and I am using IIS as the reverse proxy webserver to host the asp.net core application.

I am able to access the application inside the VM using localhost but not able to access the same from my client machine through the public ip configured for the loadbalancer.

I have configured loadbalancing rules for incoming traffic on port 80 and port 443 for the loadbalancer and specified appropriate NSGs for those ports.

Before deploying the asp.net core application I was able to access the defaultwebsite from my client machine. so I assume that inbound rules are taken in to account and working fine.

This is a self contained application and since I am able to access the application inside the VM through localhost I assume that the aspnet hosting module and other configuration required is proper.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess i have figured out what the issue is.

The Loadbalancer probe for the application is configured to be Http since its a webserver and is instructed to check at the default path "/" and since the application i have created does not serve anything on "/" its considering the node as unhealthy and does not respond or serve anything.

I changed the probe to tcp and it works just fine.

Thanks,
Teja